# Dropdown colorpicker with toggle click and timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

my code is not working and I have no idea why.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jysL5hk1/1/)

```
$(".color").click(function() {
    $(".color-picker").fadeIn(function() {
        var colorClick = $(".color-box").click();
        var timeOut = window.setTimeout(1000);
        if (colorClick || timeOut) {
            $(".color-picker").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** To clear the confusion - I want to hide the box with the colors when the user clicks on one of them $(".color-box") or on the dropdown $(".color-picker"), or if he doesn't the box should hide anyway in a couple of seconds. Sorry, I thought it was clear from my code.

**EDIT 2:** Using @AlvinMagalona's code I tried to add the timeout functionality with no success [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jysL5hk1/3/)

```
$(".color").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".color-picker").fadeIn(600);

})
.setTimeout(function() {
    if ( $(".color-picker").css('display') != 'none')  {
        $(".color-picker").hide();
    }
},3000);
$(".color-box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".color-picker").fadeOut(150);
});
```

OR I think this way is much better, but still doesn't function ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jysL5hk1/4/)):

```
$(".color").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".color-picker").fadeIn(600);
    function timeOut() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ( $(".color-picker").css('display') != 'none')  {
                $(".color-picker").hide();
            }
        },3000);
    }
});

$(".color-box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".color-picker").fadeOut(150);
});
```

The other part of the code works fine, but I'm not embedding the setTimeout function properly. Can somebody help me with that? Thanks!

**EDIT 3:**
I made it work: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jysL5hk1/6/))

```
$(".color").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".color-picker").toggle(200);

    var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
            if ( $(".color-picker").css('display') != 'none')  {
                $(".color-picker").hide();
            }
        },6000);
});
$(".color-box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".color-picker").fadeOut(150);
});
```

This one has everything I needed - when you open the drop down and click on color the box hides, when you click on the dropdown again the box hides and if you don't do any of that the box hides after couple of seconds. I hope this code will be helpful for others as well. Thanks for your help, everybody!

Comment: What is `window.delay` ? Are you trying to perform any timer operation there ?

Comment: I started with window.setTimeout() and change it to window.delay(), is this wrong?

Comment: `window.delay` is not a function (At least that's what firefox writes to the console).

Comment: @pres There is no method called `delay` in JavaScript but there is one in `jQuery`

Comment: @pres and why do you think that `window.delay` exists?

Comment: "not working" is not an adequate description. What is it supposed to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: I will never understand why people don't even look at the console output before asking for help.

Comment: Thanks for your comments: http://jsfiddle.net/jysL5hk1/1/ here is the code with the setTimeout function instead, you are absolutely right - I didn't check the console after I changed it, sorry about that.

Comment: @Barmar the description was updated and commented thoroughly, would you like to try and solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Connum the problem with the console were fixed, would you like to try and find a solution to the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question if you want to have the simplest drop-down menu where you pick something and then the drop-down box hides itself. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jysL5hk1/6/), here is the code:

```
$(".color").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".color-picker").toggle(200);

    var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
            if ( $(".color-picker").css('display') != 'none')  {
                $(".color-picker").hide();
            }
        },6000);
        console.log("timeOut");
});
$(".color-box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".color-picker").fadeOut(150);
});
```

*Special thanks to @AlvinMagalona, I've rewritten the code he proposed to make it work for my situation.*

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to hide the box after you select a color?  If you do, try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".color").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".color-picker").fadeIn(600);
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ( $(".color-picker").css('display') != 'none')  {
                $(".color-picker").hide();
            }
        },3000);
    });

    $(".color-box").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".color-picker").fadeOut(150);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works. In this case, I think that it is not necessary to stop event propagation. And as note, changing `$(".color-picker").hide()` by `$(".color-picker").fadeOut(150);` makes it more pretty 

Comment: I think stopping the event propagation is a must because clicking the    .color-box  would also trigger the    .color  click event.

Comment: @AlvinMagalona yes, I think that is exactly the problem, can you elaborate why please? And also - can you put a timeout function to hide the div if there is no user interaction?

Comment: By default propagation is enabled... When you try to trigger an event prom the child, it also triggers the same event from the parent, since the child is under the parent.  Think of it this way, inside Box A is a small Box B, When you click in side Box B, it also mean that you clicked Box A.

Comment: Since a div is inside the other, well seen.

Comment: @AlvinMagalona I really want to use your code, but I need the timeout functionality somehow embedded. I've tried to add a setTimeout function after the click event, but it's not working properly: jsfiddle.net/jysL5hk1/4 Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Do you want to hide the `.color` when the user have not yet selected a color in 3 sec?

Answer (score 2):

Try with -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".color p").click(function() {
        $(".color-picker").fadeIn();
    });
    $(".color-box").on('click', function() {
        $('.color-picker').fadeOut();
    })
});
```

It will simply open the div containing the color boxes and on clicking on that boxes will hide it with transition effect.